# Using Multiple Custom ListView Adapters inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment that contains three list views, each one of them is connected to a diffrent custom adapter.

Heres is my code:

Fragment Class:

```
package com.example.buffy;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class UserInfoFragment extends ListFragment 
{
 ListView LST_userDetail;
 ListView LST_communicationDetail;
 ListView LST_generalDetail;

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);
        Activity a = getActivity();
        LST_userDetail=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.LST_userDetailList);
        LST_communicationDetail=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.LST_communicationDetailList);
        LST_generalDetail = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.LST_generalDetailList);


        /*
         *  כאן נצטרך לחבר את המאגר המידע ולשאוב ממנו מידע, כרגע אני מכניס נתונים שרירותית
         *  מכין את האדפטור של המידע על המשתמש
         */
        ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfoData = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        userInfoData.add(new UserInfo("אלפסי עומר", "שם לקוח"));
        userInfoData.add(new UserInfo("301541541", "ת.ז"));
        userInfoData.add(new UserInfo("26/03/1988", "ת.לידה"));
        UserDetailAdapter uAdapter = new UserDetailAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.user_detail_row, userInfoData);
        LST_userDetail.setAdapter(uAdapter);


        /*
         *  כאן נצטרך לחבר את המאגר המידע ולשאוב ממנו מידע, כרגע אני מכניס נתונים שרירותית
         *  מכין את האדפטור של המידע על פרטי התקשרות
         */

        ArrayList<CommunicationInfo> comInfoData = new ArrayList<CommunicationInfo>();
        comInfoData.add(new CommunicationInfo(R.drawable.telephone, "טל. בית", "04985349334"));
        comInfoData.add(new CommunicationInfo(R.drawable.telephone, "טל. נייד", "05434983933"));
        comInfoData.add(new CommunicationInfo(R.drawable.fax, "פקס עבודה", "07435325233"));
        comInfoData.add(new CommunicationInfo(R.drawable.mail, "דוא''ל עיקרי ", "omer@b-com.co.il"));
        CommunicationUserAdaptor cAdaptor = new CommunicationUserAdaptor(getActivity(), R.layout.communitcation_detail_row, comInfoData);
        LST_communicationDetail.setAdapter(cAdaptor);


        /*
         *  כאן נצטרך לחבר את המאגר המידע ולשאוב ממנו מידע, כרגע אני מכניס נתונים שרירותית
         *  מכין את האדפטור של המידע על פרטים כללים
         */

        ArrayList<UserInfo> genInfoDate = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        genInfoDate.add(new UserInfo("סוכן", "סוכן לדוגמה"));
        genInfoDate.add(new UserInfo("בי-קום פתרונות תוכנה בע''מ", "מעסיק"));
        GeneralInfoAdapter gAdaptor = new GeneralInfoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.user_detail_row, genInfoDate);
        LST_generalDetail.setAdapter(gAdaptor);




        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);


    }

}
```

The problem is that it never reaces the getView method in the custom adapter class.
and the listview is never populated.

Anyone has any idea?

Please don't mind the funny characters

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a newly inflated view,

use `return view` instead